# How to get name value in the below json file

Tags: json, grep, jq

```
[
  {
    "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
    "name": "actual_build",
    "url": "http://tepl.tallycloudinfra.com:8080/job/actual_build/",
    "color": "blue",
    "fullname": "actual_build"
  },
  {
    "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
    "name": "CIS_TEPL_QA_Deploy",
    "url": "http://tepl.tallycloudinfra.com:8080/job/CIS_TEPL_QA_Deploy/",
    "color": "blue",
    "fullname": "CIS_TEPL_QA_Deploy"
  },
  {
    "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
    "name": "cktest",
    "url": "http://tepl.tallycloudinfra.com:8080/job/cktest/",
    "color": "red",
    "fullname": "cktest"
  },
  {
    "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
    "name": "Create_New_DB_Structure",
    "url": "http://tepl.tallycloudinfra.com:8080/job/Create_New_DB_Structure/",
    "color": "blue",
    "fullname": "Create_New_DB_Structure"
  }
]
```

I tried below jq command i'm getting this error.

Error:

```
jq -r '._class[].name' f1.json
jq: error (at f1.json:30): Cannot index array with string "_class"

jq -r '._class.name' f1.json
jq: error (at f1.json:30): Cannot index array with string "_class"
```

Answer (score 2):

With your input,

```
jq '.[].name' f1.json
```

yields

```
"actual_build"
"CIS_TEPL_QA_Deploy"
"cktest"
"Create_New_DB_Structure"
```

Comment: With a `-r` flag if the quotes aren't wanted.